# Loyalty points system

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I wanna create a loyalty system for various activities on my web app like in the Stack Over Flow with points badges etc.

Can some one point me out how to a guide on how to structure the data and store the things.

does each activity needs its own table etc ?

Comment: -1 Very few people will answer the question such as "do my job for me".

Comment: @Tadeck i am not expecting them to. i just want some one to point me to some kind of guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should look at http://code.google.com/p/stacked/ which is creating an open source version of StackOverflow.